# Common Service for multiple module

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Can someone help me out fixing this issue?
I have a service which has multiple methods each method perform some task after receiving the response from the server and then I have to pass the modified response to the respective caller component.
this is the code I have in the service.

```
 getData(observer){
          // prepare request Object
         this.httpService.getDropdownData(reqObj).subscribe(
                (data) => {

                 // modify response and then pass it to the respective component.
                  //I can't think of any solution from here. tried adding 
                   observable  but  not getting the desired output(scoping issue)


                 observer.next(data);
                 observer.complete();  
                }, (error) => {
                   // error case
            });
      }

    public observeData = new Observable(getData);


    // component code.

    this.cmpService.observeData().subscribe( response){
        do something with the response.
    };

expecting a modified output in each component.
```

Comment: Please post all the code for your service(s) and your component.

Answer (score 0):

It should better be something like:

**service:**

```
getData(): Observable<any> {
  return this.httpService.getDropdownData(reqObj).pipe(
    // do your stuffs here with the help of rxjs operators
  );
}
```

**component:**

```
this.cmpService.getData().subscribe(
  data => console.log(data), // here you'll get modified datas
  err => console.log(err),   // here, you'll manage errors in your component
  () => {}
);
```

Hope it helps ;-)

Answer (score 0):

this is what I have tried and able to achieve my goal but not sure what performance impact it has and if this is the correct way of using observable?

```
      getCmpData(): Observable<any>{

        this.spinner.show();
        let userGroups = []
        if(userData != null){
          userData = JSON.parse(userData);
            if(userData.user && userData.user.userGroups && 
                userData.user.userGroups.length){
                userGroups = userData.user.userGroups;
            }
        }
        return Observable.create(observer => {
          this.httpService.getData('cmpInfo/', userGroups)
              //.map(res => res.json())getting ts error so commented out
              .subscribe((data) => {
                if (data[0].status != 'ERROR') {
                  observer.next(data[0].results);// each component has different logic to use this data.
                  observer.complete();
                }else{
                  this.spinner.hide();
                  this.modalService.showErrorMessage();
                  observer.unsubscribe();
                }

            }, (error) => {
                this.spinner.hide();
                this.modalService.showErrorMessage();
                observer.unsubscribe();
              });
       });
  }
}
```

//component code.

```
this.cmpService.getCmpData().subscribe(
        (data) => {
            // further logic
    });
```